# Magento Custom Backend functionality

Tags: php, magento

ok i need some help with magento.  I have been using it for about 6 months now mainly using the built in functionality and have looked briefly at some of the more advanced features.  I am looking now at building in some custom features to the backend but dont know exactly where to start.

Basically, all of the documentation seems to be aimed at linking the front end etc but i want to write some custom scripts that will be interface with magentos backend upon certain events i.e. orders being placed etc.  I dont need any interface with the front end and these scripts are to run silently in the background but still integrate and use the magento database.

Where do i start? Help, please.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents : everything start with a utility called "Module Creator" that Google will help you find.
This is a ready-to-use skeleton for building module with Magento that can help you understand the MVC model of Magento.
Take a closer look at the "Adminhtml" part of the basic module you will create with Module Creator.
Then, if you want to add functionnality to the system area of your backend and use those "system variables", please take a look at the etc/system.xml files of existing module.
Have fun

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a full module for that. From the description it seems that event observers are really what you need. [This wiki article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) should be enough to get you started. Come back when you get stuck with this tutorial and I am sure someone will be able to help.